# Test a DroneDeploy App development on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, dronedeploy

I'm exploring development of a DroneDeploy App for my company and our main interest would be to use it on iOS.

For now, all our dev tests have been done using Chrome on a Linux computer, but we would like to test it on the iOS DroneDeploy application.

Are there any mean to do that?

Thanks,
Bertrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "Deploy For Mobile Testing"  you'll be able to open the app on your ipad and test it out before you submit it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFzmUMRkyH8&index=7&list=PLqOge_z8yN2EJ4ftDaY1XdbaneCRQTnvq